# Radial-gradient backgroundColor within React-PDF <View>

Tags: css, reactjs, react-pdf

I am using the React-PDF library and wanting to add a banner across the page with a radial gradient, something simple. However, when I apply the CSS property I've been using in my app, it doesn't seem to accept it...

I have been attempting to use

```
backgroundColor: 'radial-gradient(105.71% 103.23% at 74.11% 75.76%, #0d0173 0%, #1704b8 100%)',
```

Loading the page then gets the error:

[image]

I can apply a single colour easily enough, like `backgroundColor: '#0d0173';`, but of course I want the radial background :-/

This is how I am using it:

```
const styles = {
   container: {
      backgroundColor: 'radial-gradient(105.71% 103.23% at 74.11% 75.76%, #0d0173 0%, #1704b8 100%)',
      /* other css */
   },
   logo: { /* some logo css */ },
   title: { /* some title css */ }
};

return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} src={logo} />
      <Text style={styles.title}>Some text here</Text>
   </View>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, the built-in gradients use `background-image` rather than `background-color` --- as the error message tells you, it's failing to parse the color, because a gradient defintion is not a color.

Unfortunately, the solve is not just to change to `background-image`, as [it's not supported by React PDF](https://react-pdf.org/styling#valid-css-properties).

Instead, you can use an embedded SVG element to achieve the same effect, something like:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100">
    <Defs>
      <RadialGradient id="radialGradient">
        <Stop stop-color="#0d0173" />
        <Stop offset="100%" stop-color="#1704b8"/>
      </RadialGradient>
    </Defs>

    <Rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#radialGradient)" />
  </Svg>
</View>
```

Comment: Ahhh I was hoping to avoid having to do SVG stuff, but looks like it'll have to be that way. Thanks for advising.